# Submit two spark jobs simultaneously from one Scala program

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have this Scala program and I have two separate spark jobs that I want to submit to two different remote spark clusters, but I want them to be executed in parallel.

So I tried creating two threads and each submitting the job but run into this error `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).`

Are there ways to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: If you're submitting the Spark jobs to a remote cluster, there's no reason the SparkContext is even running at all in your local Scala program. Or I'm missing something. Maybe show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have two separate Spark clusters, but you are not able to connect to them from one Scala app.

For doing so, please create two Spark Sessions and connect them to two different clusters. To run the jobs, you can use scala Future to submit jobs concurrently